# Scroll a specific element inside container using JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have huge sidebar element and when the page is scrolled sidebar point to the current element that is in a viewport. But sometimes active element is out of sidebar visible space i.e below or above borders. And then the user needs to scroll manually to be able to see active element.

I want to try use logic for determining if the active element is out sidebar visible space and auto scroll if needed.

```
        $(window).on('scroll', function () {
            var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

            var container = $('#sectionMenu');
            var containerHeight = container.height();

            $(data).each(function () {
                var topDistance = $(this).offset().top - 250;
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var elem = $('#_' + id);
                if ((topDistance) < scrollTop && (topDistance + $(this).height() * 0.95) > scrollTop) {
                    if (autoScrollFlag) {
                        if (!elem.hasClass('sideBarActive')) {
                            var scrollPosition = elem.offset().top - container.offset().top;
                            removeActiveMenuItems(data);
                            elem.addClass('sideBarActive');

                            if (containerHeight < scrollPosition) {
                               // TODO automated scroll
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    autoScrollFlag = 1;
                }
            });
         });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that has worked for me was like this.

```
if (containerHeight < scrollPosition) {
    container.animate({
         scrollTop: '+=100px'
     }, 800);
}
```